# What will happen if I already own the game and it turns out to be free with Xbox live Games with gold?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

Hi I recently bought a game from Microsoft store, which turned out to be free with Xbox games with gold this month.

I already have the Xbox live gold subscription and when I browse the Games with gold section on my Xbox, it says "Owned" under that particular game (which is obvious). Will there be any alternate game title option to choose from? or anything else if this condition is met?

I had a look at [Games with Gold for Xbox FAQ](https://support.xbox.com/en-IN/my-account/xbox-live-membership/games-with-gold-faq), and I couldn't find such clause in it.

Answer (score 8):

Nope.  There is no alternative game option. The advantage here is since you actually purchased the game, if you let your gold subscription end, you can still access the game.

Comment: Are you sure? wikipedia is not canonical, but it says you do keep the game if your membership ends.

Comment: Xbox 360 GwG licences are perminant, but Xbox One GwG licences are require a current subscription.

Comment: @KellyThomas - I have a question about Xbox-ONE scenario... 1) You have an active Gold account, 2) Download a GwG free game, 3) Gold expires.  QUESTION-- What would happen with your download game... Does the download stay on your console in an "unregistered state"; Does the download get removed from your console?  What happens if you re-enable Gold account after it has expired... Do you get the game back; Is the game gone forever?

Comment: @SherlockSpreadsheets if you let your gold expire, the game is still there on the hard drive, but you won't be able to play it. You must maintain a gold membership to play any games you've acquired with this privilege.  If you renew your gold in this situation, you can play the game again.

Answer (score -2):

That is not true, as someone who cannot afford gold every month when I can get it. I collect the games and when it lapses, I can still play them, because, if you collect them with gold, you keep them permanently, no matter what.

Please stop lying to these people if you don't know what you are talking about poor people know the truth. Once you collect it, it's yours. I've even played them offline when I couldn't afford my internet for a year.